# How to get radio boxes right in PDF forms using hyperref?

Tags: pdf, forms

I would like to create a fillable PDF form containing radio buttons using `hyperref`. The text fields turn out fine. The problem is with the radio boxes. Only *one* fillable radio box is visible when opened in `evince` and `okular`. Both boxes show up in `skim` and `Preview` on MacOS, but the checks are not saved (as opposed to the text fields).

(I am aware of the `eforms` package from the `acrotex` bundle, which makes the task easier, but forms created this way cannot be filled out by `evince` and `okular`.)

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }\raisebox{-.5ex}{#2}}
\def\LayoutChoiceField#1#2{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }#2}
\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-6em

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=Name,width=\longline,borderwidth=0,bordersep=4pt,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Name}\vskip1ex

\TextField[name=Affiliation,width=\longline,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85},]{Affiliation}\vskip1ex

\ChoiceMenu[borderwidth=0,radio=true,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Are you a}{Student, Academic}\
\TextField[name=Comment,multiline=true,width=\longline,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Comments}\\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong with the radio boxes? Or is this an issue with the `poppler` library?

Comment: @LianTze: Not directly responding to your question – I get an error for `bordergap`, perhaps this should be `bordersep`?

Comment: @doncherry So it should, thank you! I've corrected the error.

Comment: After some further googling (sorry I didn't have time to do it properly yesterday), this seems to be a poppler bug as described at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/531516.

If a moderator feels that this question should then be closed, I will be happy to do so. In the meantime, PDF XChange Viewer (Windows only unfortunately) seems to be the best free tool for filling in these PDF forms.

Comment: As for other viewers, Adobe Reader 10.0.1 on Win7 works fine with your example.

Comment: @LianTze Lim: Adobe Reader isn't less free than PDF-XChange Viewer. They both are freeware. And all PDF viewers were, and are, behind Adobe Reader on functionality.

Comment: @Karl Karlsson: I'm sorry, I meant "freeware", not "free" when I wrote about PDF XChange Viewer. Thanks for reminding me. @doncherry: The reason I didn't mention Adobe Reader, is because if you do not also have a copy of Adobe *Acrobat*, you will not be able to save the form as a PDF after it's been filled out; you can only export it to a plain text field-and-value file. XChange Viewer, on the other hand, _does_ allow you to save the filled-out form as a PDF (under a different name).

Comment: Based on @LianTze's comment, I'm closing this as 'off topic'. It's not actually related directly to TeX, but is a viewer issue.