# Settings for hypertext in multiline environment

Tags: pdf, forms

I am writing this question after seeing [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/how-to-get-radio-boxes-right-in-pdf-forms-using-hyperref) as I had no idea that you could make forms like that in TeX.

Playing a bit with the code in that example I came across two issues I could not find how to change with the `\TextField[parameters]{label}`environment.

How to set the number of lines in a multiline environment and how to move the label at the top rather than the bottom of the multiline box.

According to the [manual](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-210006.2) the option for the multiline environment is just a boolean parameter

> multiline   boolean    false    whether text box is multiline

and the label appears at the bottom rather than the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To specify the height of a multiline text fielf, use the optional argument `height`, such as

   ```
   \TextField[multiline=true,height=6\baselineskip,...]{Comments}\
   ```
2. For vertical alignment, you could use `\height` which gives he height of a box, together with `\raisebox`, such as

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }%
     \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}
   ```
3. You could even adjust the default height of a multiline text field, like

   ```
   \renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip}
   ```

Here's a complete example for this, re-using the code of the linked question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultHeightofTextMultiline}{6\baselineskip} 
\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}
%\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{% or this or similar ...
  %\raisebox{-\height}{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }}\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}
\def\LayoutChoiceField#1#2{\makebox[6em][l]{#1: }#2}
\newdimen\longline
\longline=\textwidth\advance\longline-6em
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[name=Name,width=\longline,borderwidth=0,bordersep=4pt,
  backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Name}\vskip1ex

\TextField[name=Affiliation,width=\longline,borderwidth=0,
  backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85},]{Affiliation}\vskip1ex

\ChoiceMenu[borderwidth=0,radio=true,
  backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Are you a}{Student, Academic}\\

\TextField[name=Comment,multiline=true,height=6\baselineskip,
  width=\longline,borderwidth=0,backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}]{Comments}\\
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason that the same code does not provide the same results with XeLatex? Everything appears to be misaligned again. I am using Xelatex for the fontspec package as I am trying to use a system font not available to pdftex

Comment: @o4tlulz Interesting! I noticed that too. However, it works fine with LuaLaTeX. Could you use that?

Comment: I have a question, when I use `backgroundcolor`, it changes the background color when I click on the field, but as soon I filled the field and press enter, the default background color comes back. Any idea why ?

Comment: it works perfectly for me until a few \textfield. After i do like 4 they start to group together in pairs so it just messes with the spacing between the text fields