# Making fillable forms in LaTeX using TextField and CheckBox

Tags: hyperref, printing, forms

This is what I got so far with the code given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter

\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}[action=http://your-web-server.com/path/receiveform.cgi]

\begin{tabular}{ll>{\centering}p{0.6cm}ll}
Name: & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=5cm] &  & Name: & Need TextField here  \tabularnewline
Client's Name: & \TextField[height=0.01cm, width=5cm] &  & Advisor Name: & \rule{5cm}{1pt}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{0.3cm}

Have you ? \hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm] \enspace{} Yes
\hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm] \enspace{} No


\Submit{Submit}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

**Questions**

1. How to control the height of `TextField` as two `TextField`s are overlapping?
2. How to change color of `TextField`?
3. How to make two `CheckBox`es mutually exclusive so only one can be checked at once?

An help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the height of a textfield with the height option or by redefining \DefaultHeightofText. But the *minimal* height of the field will always be the height of the surrounding box. In a tabular cell (which contains a \strut) this is the height of the cell. If you want to avoid this you can add an additional box:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
%suppress the label:
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  #2%
}
\begin{Form}
\def\DefaultHeightofText{5pt}

\mbox{\strut\TextField[width=3cm]{namea}} \mbox{\TextField[width=3cm]{namea}}


\begin{tabular}{ll}
Name: & \mbox{\TextField[width=3cm]{namea}} \\%smaller
Name: & \TextField[width=3cm]{namea}
\end{tabular}


\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ulrike for helpful answer. Would appreciate if you can guide me how to get green color `TextField`s? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Rather then `tabular` environment you can use `multicol` package to split your fields on two columns, in this case you can modify height of textfield as you like

More detail can be found in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25583/54817)

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent0pt

\renewcommand*{\LayoutTextField}[2]{\makebox[7em][l]{#1: }%
  \raisebox{\baselineskip}{\raisebox{-\height}{#2}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{Form}[action=http://your-web-server.com/path/receiveform.cgi]

\begin{multicols}{2}
 \TextField[name=name, width=4cm, color=0.18 0.55 0.34, % seagreen
          bordercolor=1 0 1, charsize=9pt]{Name} \vskip2ex
 \TextField[name=client ,width=4cm]{Client's Name}       

 \columnbreak

 \TextField[name=name2,width=4cm]{Name} \vskip2ex
  Advisor Name:  \rule{4cm}{1pt}
\end{multicols}

\vspace*{0.3cm}

\noindent
Have you ? \hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm]{Yes}
\hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm]{No}

\noindent
\Submit{Submit}
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. In general, the height of a `TextField` is controlled by the macro `\DefaultHeightofText`; I can't tell you why it does not work in a table.  I had this issue also once and I gave up on it.  It works in regular text (see below).
2. You can change to color of text inside `TextField` with `color` key.  The color spec must be in RGB triple, in the range 0..1.  There is also a `bordercolor` key.
3. `CheckBox`es and `TextField`s take a mandatory `label` argument.  This `label` is used to make them unambiguous.  If you want to leave this argument empty, use the `name` key for a unique label.

Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}[action=http://your-web-server.com/path/receiveform.cgi]

\noindent \def\DefaultHeightofText{5pt}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.6cm}ll}
  Name: &  \TextField[name=name, width=5cm, color=0.18 0.55 0.34, % seagreen
          bordercolor=1 0 1, charsize=9pt, height=3pt]{}
        &  & Name: & Need TextField here \\
  Client's Name: & \TextField[name=client, width=5cm]{}
                 &  & Advisor Name: & \rule{5cm}{1pt}
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{0.3cm}

\noindent
Have you ? \hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm]{Yes}
\hfill{} \CheckBox[height=0.01cm, width=0.4cm]{No}

\noindent
\Submit{Submit}

\vspace{3ex}

\def\DefaultHeightofText{5pt}
\TextField{5pt}

\vspace{3ex}

\def\DefaultHeightofText{\baselineskip}
\TextField{baselineskip}

\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks @Arash for your answer. I need `TextField` in the last column of the table. Would appreciate if you address that too. Thanks

Comment: Just add `\TextField[width=4cm]{}` to the last column

Comment: @MYaseen208 - Maybe I'm missing something, you can add a `TextField` in the last column by adding something like `\TextField[name=namei, width=5cm]{}`.  Just make sure you have a unique value to `name` key.