# How do I create a text box that will have a fixed size and could be filled with text after the pdf is compiled?

Tags: text-manipulation, textfield

I'm sure this has been answered already but I couldn't find it.

Because I have no idea how it's called I don't know what tag to use, this may have nothing to do with text manipulation.

I want to make a form with empty boxes that the user could write in (change the text after the pdf compiles).

I should be able to:

1. Set the color inside the box
2. Set the size of the box

Please include in the answer all packages required and an example would also be appreciated.

Comment: search for TextField hyperref

Comment: [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345568/146828) answers more than what you ask...  Yes, `\TextField[...options...]{tag}` does the trick that comes with the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, minimal example to get started for just what you want:

[image: Textbox image with \TextField]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\TF}[2][15em]{\TextField[borderwidth=0.1pt,
                                     width=#1,
                                     height=1.25em,
                                     charsize=10pt,
                                     backgroundcolor=blue!50!gray!20,
                                     color=blue!33!black,
                                     bordercolor=red!20,
                                     name=#2
                                    ]{}}

\begin{document}

My name is: \TF{a}\\

I would like to: \TF[25em]{b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes! How do you call these text boxes with user defined text? 
I asked the most inaccurate question without the name, well done for understanding what I meant.
Thank you very very much

Comment: In general computer terminology, they are called "text-box", while we use the LaTeX command `\TextField` to invoke that.  Welcome.

Comment: A follow up question, is there a way to have that in a way that does not require a different instance of every command (without needing the names a and b)?
To be used in big tables and such

Comment: Using the macro `\TF{tag}` you can use as many text boxes you like.  I put in an optional argument `\TF[width]{tag}` in case you want a text box with a different width than the default value (`15em` here).  If you need more optional arguments, try [this](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-twooptarg).  Otherwise, if all textboxes you need are to be of the same color, width, etc., just use something like `Name: TF{a}\\ Place: \TF{b}\\ Phone: \TF{c}\\ ...\\ Hobby: \TF{p}`.  For a table just replace the `:` with `&` and embed in a `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand the question. Empty boxes can be done with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{sharp corners}

\begin{document}
Name: \tcbox[colback=red!30, on line]{\hspace*{3cm}}

Explain what you want
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!20, height=5cm]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to create the pdf such that a user can enter text in the boxes and change that text. Like a form.