# How to create a form with a text field where characters are in separated boxes?

Tags: box, forms, textfield

I would like to create a form (at least printable) containing a field where each character is separated from the previous one.

Something similar to the field A in this picture :

[image: Adobe field example]

What is the name of this type of field ? And/Or what is the option to activate ?

Is there a way to make this version (with unclosed box) :

[image]

Thank you very much !

EDIT : if the digital version creating a form in PDF is not possible... is there a way to create only a graphical field ?

Comment: these are comb fields, you get them e.g. with `\TextField[comb,maxlen=3,name=accountA,width=3em]{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ulrik Fischer, I now know it is named "comb fields".

To make something like field A (full closed cells) :

```
\TextField[comb,maxlen=3,name=accountA,width=3em]{}
```

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence. l.4 \TextField

Comment: @wipet : I believe it is found in the "_hyperref_" package. I found multiple examples using it with this. (I completely forgot where I needed the CombField) 

[example1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345568/making-fillable-forms-in-latex-using-textfield-and-checkbox)

[example2 (in french)](https://blog.dorian-depriester.fr/latex/creer-des-formulaire-pdf-editables)

Answer (score 3):

When using `l3pdffield`s, you can use

```
\DocumentMetadata{} %loads pdfmanagement-testphase
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3pdffield-testphase} % for form fields

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdffield_textfield:n{MaxLen=3,setfieldflags={comb},name=accountA,width=3em}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```